# speed up R for loop

Tags: r, performance, for-loop

i want to calculate cumulative loss at each set of iterations. i.e. let's say my `n_sim <-1000` and `x=rep(3,n_sim)`.

in the above case, set of iteration is 3 and number of set of iteration is 1000, so total 3000 (1000*3) iterations.
Let's define below:
`Iter <- rep(1:n_sim, x)`, `Val <-rnorm(3*n_sim)`, `df<-data.frame(Iter,Val)`.

**problem**:i want to calculate sum of `Val` taking each set of iteration meaning as here a set consist of 3 iterations, i want to take `Val` of first 3 iterations and calculate sum and so on. So i will have a final vector of length 1000 containing sum of `Val` of each set.

I have tried below using `for` loops, but it is very very slow while doing 1mn simulations.

`sum_value <-array(0,c(n_sim))
for(i in 1: n_sim) {
 sum_value[i] = df[df$Iter==i,] %>% .$Val %>% sum
}`
Anyone has better  idea how to fast this process.

Comment: `colSums(matrix(DF$Val, nrow = 3))`?

Comment: Thanks Roland for quick reply. for this example it may work taking ```nrow=3````. However i am looking at dynamic nrow. it may be of multiple values as well. For e.g instead of setting this set of iteration to constant 3, it may vary i.e. some set may contain 3 iterations, some may contain 4 and so on.

Comment: Thank you Roland. `aggregate`  does the job very fast.

Comment: Fast is relative. `aggregate` is actually quite slow.